# Console app not posting to minimalistic ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a solution with two projects in Visual Studio 2022:

- A console app
- A minimalistic API created using ASP.NET Core Web API

The API has a simplistic model as follows:

```
class Todo // This is the model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}
```

Which ought to represent Todo items in a small database, similar to the tutorial shown in the ASP.NET [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). The API has `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` methods.

The `POST` method looks like this:

```
// POST
app.MapPost("/todoitems", (Todo todo, TodoDb db) =>
{
    db.Todos.Add(todo);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Results.Created($"/todoitems/{todo.Id}", todo);
});
```

I decided to make synchronous calls to simplify this a little bit.

The console application attempts to make use of the `POST` method exposed by the API to add a Todo item in the database. Here's what I was able to do so far, thanks to the REST client tutorial in the Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Json;

namespace InteractWithTodoApi
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client  = new HttpClient();
        private static string repoLink = "https://localhost:7157/todoitems";

        private static async Task PostData()
        {
            JsonContent content = JsonContent.Create("{\"id\": 1, \"Name\": \"Wash dishes\", \"IsComplete\": true}", typeof(string));
            HttpResponseMessage postTask = await client.PostAsync(repoLink, content);

            Console.WriteLine(postTask.Content);
        }   

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await PostData();
        }
    }
}
```

I then launch the API with a localhost, and once it is up and running I execute the console app. Then I refresh the API in my browser under `https://localhost:PORT/todoitems`.

After I refresh my browser, I expect to see a new entry
corresponding to:

```
{ "Id": 1, "Name": "Wash dishes", "IsComplete": true }"
```

The console app doesn't crash and runs to completion, however when I refresh that browser, I see that my Todo list is still empty: `[]`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you debug the server and put a breakpoint in your `MapPost` handler, is it getting called?

Comment: If I start the Web API project with debugging enabled, Visual Studio won't allow me to start any other projects at the same time...

Comment: But Getting data using `client.GetStringAsync` seems to work just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that specifying the header is important while interacting with a JSON-based API. There appear to be two ways of doing this while working with `System.Net.Http`

1. Set globally using something like:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

2. Set for each POST request  as follows:

```
string JsonString = "{\"name\": \"Wash dishes\", \"isComplete\": true}";
StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

The default is not `application/json` in `System.Net.Http`. It appears to be some other kind of text-based value.

Comment: For using `POST`, you typically also need to define a `Content-Type` header with a value of `application/json` to make it clear that you're posting JSON data. That's what you're implicitly doing in your second example (defining `application/json` on your `StringContent` object - surprised your first approach works, though ...

Comment: I actually didn't really try the first one, but I assume it should work... The second one definitely does.